# Permission in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, permissions

I have a jobs pages where users can create new jobs edit and destroy their jobs and I want to let user edit or destroy only their post only if are connected else they will returned to the job show page for this i have this code in my job controller

```
def require_login
  @job = current_user.jobs.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  redirect_to job_path if @job.nil?
end

  before_action :login_required
  def login_required
    redirect_to new_user_session_path unless user_signed_in?
  end
  before_action :login_required, :require_login, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

the only part where this don't work is when i not connected and try to edit my job it redirect me to the log in form but after login it redirect me to the home page instead of the edit page

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the code block you pasted looks weird, for three reasons:

1. Indentation is wrong
2. You have `before_action :login_required` twice and it's not even the same
3. From the methods names it's unclear what you want exactly

From what you wrote, you want a user to edit or destroy a job only if they are logged in - otherwise you want to send them to the jobs index page. If that's right, the code in your controller should look **like** this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    # your code here
  end

  def update
    # your code here
  end

  def destroy
    # your code here
  end

private
  def require_login
    redirect_to job_path unless user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Comment: I got a downvote for this answer but no explanation about why, would really appreciate a comment.